# how to test react-native-qrcode-scanner with @testing-library/react-native and jest

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking, react-native-testing-library

I have used this qr scanner in my application but I'm having trouble doing unit testing on the qr scanner. how to do unit testing on this qr scanner? should i mock that or there is a way to send values to onRead props?

before, I have tried to mock react-native-qrcode-scanner with this code

```js
jest.mock('react-native-qrcode-scanner', () => {
    const React = require('react');
    const PropTypes = require('prop-types');
    return class MockQRCodeScanner extends React.Component {
        static propTypes = { children: PropTypes.any };
        static defaultProps = { reactivate: false }
    
        render() {
          return React.createElement('react-native-qrcode-scanner', this.props, this.props.children);
        }
    }
})
```

but gives an error "TypeError: scanner.current.reactivate is not a function"

this my code :
ScanQRCodeScreen.js

```js
'use strict';
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import { 
    View, 
    StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';

const ScanQRCodeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
    const scanner = React.useRef(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        navigation.addListener('focus', async() => {
            await scanner.current.reactivate();
        });
    },[]);

    const onSuccess = e => {
        console.log(e.data);
    }
 
    return (
        <View>
            <QRCodeScanner
                onRead={onSuccess}
                ref={scanner}
                showMarker={true}
            />
        </View>
    );
};
```

ScanQRCodeScreen-test.js

```js
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
import { render, act } from '@testing-library/react-native';

import ScanQRCodeScreen from '../screens/ScanQRCodeScreen';

jest.mock('react-native-qrcode-scanner', () => {
    const React = require('react');
    const PropTypes = require('prop-types');
    return class MockQRCodeScanner extends React.Component {
        static propTypes = { children: PropTypes.any };
        static defaultProps = { reactivate: false }
    
        render() {
          return React.createElement('react-native-qrcode-scanner', this.props, this.props.children);
        }
    }
});

let wrapper = null;
const map = {};
const mockedParams = {
    navigation: {
        addListener: jest.fn((events, cb) => {
            map[events] = cb
        })
    },
};
beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = render(
        <ScanQRCodeScreen {...mockedParams}/>
    );
})

describe('<Renderable>', () => {
    test('ScanQRCodeScreen snapshot', async() => {
        await act(async() => map.focus());
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
})
```